# Sqlite query for another result if first is null cursor window allocation error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-cursor

I have the following tables on my Sqlite database: PRODUCTS, PRODUCT_VALUES and PAYMENT_FORMS and this is their respective columns.

### PRODUCTS

```
+----+---------------+
| id | product_name  | 
+----+---------------+
|  1 | COMPUTER      |
|  2 | CELLPHONE     |
|  3 | LAPTOP        |
+----+---------------+
```

### PAYMENT_METHOD

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | CASH                |
|  2 | CREDIT              |
|  3 | 3X_CREDIT           |
+----+---------------------+
```

### PRODUCT_VALUES

This table stores the value of the product based on the payment method, so a product can have multiple values, like $15.67 on cash and $16.30 on credit. But lets say the product doesn't have a value set for 3x on credit, so in this case I need to get the value on cash, the first one on the table below.

```
+-------------------+------------+---------+
| payment_method_id | product_id | value   |
+-------------------+------------+---------+
|                 1 |          1 |   15.67 |
|                 2 |          1 |   16.30 |
|                 3 |          1 |    NULL |
+-------------------+------------+---------+
```

Right now I'm need to display the product name, and value based on the payment method and I'm doing it using the following select:

```
    public ArrayList<Products> getProducts(int paymentMethodId) {

  ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();

  // Cursor for the product search
  Cursor cursor = null;

  // Cursor for the product value search
  Cursor valuesCursor = null;

  // Products columns
  String[] columns = { Products.ID, Products.NAME };

  // Values columns
  String[] valuesColumns = { ProductsValues.VALUE };

  try {

    // Get all products on the table
    cursor = conn.query(Products.TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

      cursor.moveToFirst();

      do {

        try {

          Products product = new Products();

          int productId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Produtos.ID));
          String productName = cursor.getInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Produtos.NAME)));
          product.setId(productId);
          product.setName(productName);

          // Gets the product value
          try{

            // Searchs the value based on the paymentMethodId
            valuesCursor = conn.query(ProductsValues.TABLE, valuesColumns, ProductsValues.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(paymentMethodId)}, null, null, null, null);

            if (valuesCursor != null && valuesCursor.getCount() > 0) {

              valuesCursor.moveToFirst();
              product.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(valuesCursor.getDouble(valuesCursor.getColumnIndex(ProductsValues.VALUE))));

            } else {

              // Searchs using the paymentMethodId 1
              valuesCursor = conn.query(ProductsValues.TABLE, valuesColumns, ProductsValues.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID + " = 1", null, null, null, null, null);

              if (valuesCursor != null && valuesCursor.getCount() > 0) {

                valuesCursor.moveToFirst();
                product.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(valuesCursor.getDouble(valuesCursor.getColumnIndex(ProductsValues.VALUE))));

              }

            }

          } catch (SQLiteException e){

            Log.e("TAG", "getProducts: Error selecting products", e);

          } finally {

            // Closes the valuesCursor
            if (aluesCursor != null) {

              aluesCursor.close();

            }

          }

          // ADD the product on the Array
          products.add(product);

        } catch (SQLiteException e){

          Log.e("TAG", "getProducts: Error selecting products", e);

        }
        // Repeats for the next product
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

  } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    Log.e("TAG", "getProducts: Error selecting products", e);

  } finally {

    // Closes the products cursor
    if (cursor != null) {

      cursor.close();

    }

  }

  return products;

}
```

Then based on the product_id and the payment_method_id I select the value, but if the result is null I do the same select again using the payment_method_id 1, which is mandatory, therefore not null. After this I set the values on my Product object and return the result to my Activity to be displayed.

But when there's many products, around 2000, I'm getting a Cursor window allocation error with 967 cursors open.

Is there a way of doing this select more efficiently?

Comment: The error occurs because you leak the `valuesCursor` when you get 0 results for the specific paymentId. Insert `valuesCursor.close()` right after `// Searchs using the paymentMethodId 1` to get rid of that error. Or, preferably, use a `SELECT` statement to fetch the data you want in a single query. This should be *much* more efficient.

Comment: @JimmyB Thanks, it worked! But anyway it wold be much better to have a single select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [rawQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) to execute the appropriate SQL statement using a *JOIN*. Like:

```
SELECT
p.id, p.product_name, IFNULL(pv.value,pv2.value) AS value
FROM
PRODUCTS p
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_VALUES pv2 ON p.id = pv2.product_id AND pv2.payment_method_id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_VALUES pv ON p.id = pv.product_id AND pv.payment_method_id = ?
```

Explanation:

We select the products' data from `PRODUCTS` and make an `INNER JOIN` on `PRODUCT_VALUES` with the `payment_method_id` 1, which always exists. Additionally, we perform another `OUTER JOIN` on `PRODUCT_VALUES` with the specific `payment_method_id` we want.

If the specific `payment_method_id` does not exist for the product the values from the outer join will all be `null`. Hence, we use `IFNULL(pv.value,pv2.value)` to return the specific value iff one is found (= not null), or the default value for `payment_method_id = 1` otherwise.

Comment: I've tried using the rawQuery() but when I needed to get the values using the payment_method_id = 3 it returned the value from the first line of the table, but only showed 2 products, the ones that the value of id 3 weren't set. I'll try to find a way to improve your select. Thanks anyway!